# user agent string explanation

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, user-agent

This may be a simple question for some but I'd like it explained.
I am just learning about user agent strings so keep it simple please,

here is an example

```
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Baiduspider" bad_bot
    #
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    Deny from env=bad_bot
```

what id like to know is what exactly is the `^` for and what does it do in regards to this example ?.
also, is there a way to wildcard such as `Baidu`  or  `spider` instead of `Baiduspider`
So anything that starts, contains or ends with `Baidu`  or  `spider` gets treated 
the same way as it would in this case as `Baiduspider` gets handled ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` in regex is used for start of text.

> is there a way to wildcard such as Baidu or spider instead of Baiduspider

Yes you can use:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "(Baidu|spider)" bad_bot
```

[Read About Regular Expressions](http://regular-expressions.info)

Comment: thanks for reply, so in your example the ^ would not be needed ?

Comment: No `^` won't be needed since you wanted **`anything that starts, contains or ends with Baidu or spider`**